# Android contacts permission granted without asking at runtime

Tags: java, android, permissions

I'm trying to request the ability to read contacts in an app, and have followed several tutorials. All of these use nearly the same code for this process. Below is the code in my MainActivity.java file, that should request permission.

```
private void checkContactPermissions()
    {
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Contacts permission NOT granted");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
        }
        else
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "Contacts permission granted");
            readContacts();
        }
    }
```

My manifest.xml also includes the line:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

When the app is run, either on emulator or physical debugging device, it does not ask for permission, however the log states that the permission was granted. I have confirmed the permission is off by going to the settings and checking it was turned off. What else would be causing the app to perform as if permissions were granted.

Comment: change this == to !=  after this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)

Comment: I really can't believe I was this blind. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Divyesh Patel pointed out, I had the boolean statemetns mixed up, it should be

```
ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
```

Rather than

```
ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this,

```
private Context mContext=YourActivity.this;

private static final int REQUEST = 112;

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
    String[] PERMISSIONS = {android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS};
    if (!hasPermissions(mContext, PERMISSIONS)) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) mContext, PERMISSIONS, REQUEST );
    } else {
        readContacts();
    }
} else {
    readContacts();
}
```

get Permissions Result

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    readContacts();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "The app was not allowed to read your contact", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

check permissions  for marshmallow

```
private static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I use [**RxPermission**](https://github.com/tbruyelle/RxPermissions) for permissions to make my code ultimately short.

First add these permissions (or one you need) in your `manifest.xml`.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Then ask run time permission from user in your activity.

```
RxPermissions rxPermissions = new RxPermissions(this);
rxPermissions
.request(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) // ask single or multiple permission once
.subscribe(granted -> {
    if (granted) {
       // All requested permissions are granted
    } else {
       // At least one permission is denied
    }
});
```

add this library in your `build.gradle`

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.tbruyelle:rxpermissions:0.10.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding:2.1.1'
}
```

**Isn't this easy?**

Answer (score 0):

Important thing for you to note here that these permissions are asked only for devices with version>23 and if you have lower version of android then for only some models like redmi you have to invoke the permissions manually .

Otherwise version<23 generally do not ask for permissions.
If you put in manifest. It will automatically take it, specially when you are installing app over usb.

Answer (score 0):

If any device has OS version below <23 or In app manifist file maxtarget version is below <23 then it will not ask permission in runtime because while the app installing on these devices you actually giving permission to all you mentioned.

So the runtime permissions are possible only in the case of device has OS version above 22(Lolipop).

Hope this helpful..

@Rajesh

Comment: Hi Rajesh. I've already specified the required permissions in the manifest for OS versions 23 and below, but I'm testing on APIs 24 and 25 for runtime permissions, and they weren't coming up. As it turns out, I just had my boolean statement wrong.