# Add to contacts not performed immediately after permission is granted

Tags: java, android, contacts, android-contacts, mobile-phones

In my Android application (written in Java) I have a feature to add a contact to the user's phone using scanned information. The feature works perfectly once the user grants the application permission to edit the device's contacts. However, after granting permission the user needs to press the 'Add to Contacts' button again since the action was not performed, to begin with. It's as if the original command was thrown out in lew of asking the user for permission to do that action.
Is there any way to make it so that the contact is added immediately after permission is granted? A user using the application for the first time would not know that the first time they add a contact they need to press the button a second time after granting permission.

Here is the code for the 'Add to Contacts' method:

```
private void addToContact(View v) {
    //if the permission if off
    Ask.on(this)
            .forPermissions(Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS)
            .go();

    int phoneType = 1;
    int emailType = 1;

    // Prepare contact creation request
    //
    // Note: We use RawContacts because this data must be associated with a
    // particular account.
    // The system will aggregate this with any other data for this contact
    // and create a coresponding entry in the ContactsContract.Contacts provider for us.
    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
            .newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
            .build());
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
            .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
            .withValue(
                    ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME,
                    mContactName).build());
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
            .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
            .withValue(
                    ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                    mContactPhoneNumber)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
                    phoneType).build());
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
            .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
            .withValue(
                    ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA,
                    mContactEmail)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE,
                    emailType).build());
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
            .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
            .withValue(
                    ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.COMPANY,
                    mContactOrg)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TITLE,
                    mContactTitle)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE,
                    1).build());
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
            .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
            .withValue(
                    ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.FORMATTED_ADDRESS,
                    mContactAddress).build());

    // Ask the Contact provider to create a new contact
    Log.i(TAG, "Selected account: " + ACCOUNT_TYPE + " (" + ACCOUNT_NAME
            + ")");
    Log.i(TAG, "Creating contact: " + mContactName);
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
    Context ctx = getApplicationContext();
    try {
        getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(ctx, "contact created  successfully",
                duration);
        toast.show();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Display warning

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(ctx, "contact creation failed",
                duration);
        toast.show();

        // Log exception
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception encountered while inserting contact: " + e);
    }
}
```

Here is where the method is called:

```
mAddToContactButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            addToContact(v);
        }
    });
```

Comment: explain a bit more.Add your code too.

Comment: @Danish I will add my code, but the code works perfectly after the user grants permission. Basically, when the app is first used and the 'add to contacts' button is pressed, the app asks for permission to edit the phone's contacts. After given, the user would expect the contact to have been added but it has not been. The user needs to press the button again to add their first contact. After that there are no issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the answer to this question to make it work:[Android contacts permission granted without asking at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43493446/android-contacts-permission-granted-without-asking-at-runtime) @Marmor was correct in what the issue was, however, the Ask function was not working. With Android 23 and higher more is needed.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an issue with Android or ContactsContract, it's about your usage of [`Ask`](https://github.com/00ec454/Ask).

Ask supports a callback you can add when a request is granted to your app, you need to add it and call your method again. Something like this:

```
@AskGranted(Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS)
public void writeContactsGranted(int id) {
    Log.i(TAG, "the permission was granted, calling 'addToContact' again");
    // call addToContact() here with the view you need.
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! My question now is how to make the calls and where to put this method. Currently, the addToContact() method is called when the user clicks the 'Add to Contacts' button. Would I call writeContactsGranted? How would I then get the view passed to that method?

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty sure the view is never used so I'm going to take it out. So just to be clear, all I need to do is add this method to the activity and call addToContacts() within it again?

Comment: You can try this in the @AskGranted(Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS)
public void writeContactsGranted(int id) {
    Log.i(TAG, "the permission was granted, calling 'addToContact' again");
    mAddToContactButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            addToContact(v);
        }
    }); 
}

Comment: dont forget to initialise the button using findviewbyid before maddtocontactbutton.setonclicklistener

Comment: I tried calling the method directly and it was never called. I then tried to add the click listener inside that method and it said 'contact creation failed.

Comment: Is there somewhere that I should be calling writeContactsGranted()?

Comment: I am not familiar with this library so u need to wait for marmor reply or you can use other library(dexter library) or default android way of asking permission.

Comment: @AskGranted(Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS) public void writeContactsGranted(int id) { Log.i(TAG, "the permission was granted, calling 'addToContact' again");  
mAddToContactButton=findViewById(R.id.your_button); //have you added this line mAddToContactButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() { public void onClick(View v) { addToContact(v); } }); }